# Joomla3 module ajax - display accented characters

Tags: ajax, joomla

I am trying to edit the sample Joomla3 module to display characters with accents and other characters. The module works like this: into the form, fill in any text, then click on the "send" button. 
Embedded text appears at the bottom of the module. The module is working, but when you entered into for example text: "řecký" appears only: "eck". Could you please advise someone how to modify the code 
to display characters with accents and special characters?

This is the "[Ajax Hello World Module](https://github.com/Joomla-Ajax-Interface/Hello-Ajax-World-Module)".

It may be necessary to edit the file mod_hello_ajax_world.php:

```
<?php defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Include the helper.
require_once __DIR__ . '/helper.php';

// Instantiate global document object
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$js = <<<JS
(function ($) {
    $(document).on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function () {
        var value   = $('input[name=data]').val(),
            request = {
                    'option' : 'com_ajax',
                    'module' : 'hello_ajax_world',
                    'data'   : value,
                    'format' : 'raw'
                };
        $.ajax({
            type   : 'POST',
            data   : request,
            success: function (response) {
                $('.status').html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery)
JS;

$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);

require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_hello_ajax_world');
```

The same problem (do not display accented characters or special characters) are also at the demonstration module "[Ajax-Session-Module](https://github.com/Joomla-Ajax-Interface/Ajax-Session-Module)".

Thank you.

Comment: You must see where the encoding is wrong.. when arriving to the controller or only on the view?

Comment: miguelmpn, thank you for your response. The text contains accented characters I have never found in any PHP variable 
in the module or in /components/com_ajax/ajax.php.
 
The module has only four files: mod_hello_ajax_world.xml, mod_hello_ajax_world.php (code above),  helper.php and tmpl/default.php The module communicates with com_ajax component that is part of Joomla from version 3.2.

Comment: In Firebug console a text sent in POST has correct encoding. But the response (Firebug console) no contains the accented characters.

Comment: I can only remember to check the database field encoding (if you are using), and the encoding of the PHP file's on your module.

Also you can check if the Joomla ajax.php is striping the special characters.. (I can't look at it now)

Comment: this might help too http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-an-ajax-call-in-component

Answer (score 0):

@miguelmpn thank you for your comment. You're right, Joomla com_ajax/ajax.php is striping the special characters. It was necessary to modify the code in the module file helper.php

instead of the original:

```
$data = $input-> get('data');
```

use:

```
$data = $input-> get('data', '', 'RAW');
```

and already everything is in order. Thank you.